# PHP regex to extract everything after public_html

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Probably a simple one but I have file paths like `/var/www/html/mysite/releases/20130123113638/public_html/images/image.jpg`
where the release path is constantly changing. I need to extract just the path after public_html - can anyone advise the best way to do this? Many thanks

Comment: Have you actually tried anything? Such as looking at the various [string manipulation functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) PHP offers?

Comment: Something like this? `#/var/www/html/mysite/releases/([0-9]+)/public_html/images/image.jpg#i`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need:

```
$text = '/var/www/html/mysite/releases/20130123113638/public_html/images/image.jpg';
preg_match('/public_html(.*)$/Usmi', $text, $res);
echo $res[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `regex` for this, use can use some simple [string](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) function like `strrpos()` and `substr()`, for example:

```
$path = "/var/www/html/mysite/releases/20130123113638/public_html/images/image.jpg";
$index = strrpos($path, "public_html/");
$path = substr($path, $index + 12);
// $path is now equal to 'images/image.jpg'
```